# How move the first child to the bottom of parent, under last child?

Tags: html, css

I need to move to first div (id="div-1") to bottom of parent div (id="content") under 
last div (id="div-4")

But the first div move over last div

[image: See image]

I need it to be

[image: See image]

```css
#content {
  position: relative;
}

#div-1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>id="container"</p>
  <div id="div-1">
    <p>id="div-1"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-2">
    <p>id="div-2"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-3">
    <p>id="div-3"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-4">
    <p>id="div-4"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please complete the snippet I made to show a [mcve]

Comment: If to to solve that with the content flow properly, use Flexbox and its `order` property: https://jsfiddle.net/rmfhz0ev/

Answer (score 2):

Add `transform: translateY(100%);` to first div.

```css
#content {
  position: relative;
}

#div-1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>id="container"</p>
  <div id="div-1">
    <p>id="div-1"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-2">
    <p>id="div-2"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-3">
    <p>id="div-3"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-4">
    <p>id="div-4"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML/CSS**

`Add transform: translateY(100%) to #div-1`

**JavaScript:**
You could use the fragment method.

1) Declare a fragment:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
```

2) Append desired element to the fragment:

```
fragment.appendChild(document.getElementById('source'));
```

3) Append fragment to desired element:

```
document.getElementById('destination').appendChild(fragment);
```

In your case;

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.appendChild(document.getElementById('div1'));
document.getElementById('div2').appendChild(fragment);
```

Codepen
https://codepen.io/Sujithgopinath/pen/XBGbRN

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it might be possible using purely CSS. Anyway, I have written a solution for you using jQuery which targets the first `<div>` inside `#content` and moves it to the last position/bottom.

Useful refs :

> 1) [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) : The CSS pseudo-class represents the first element of its type among a group of sibling elements.
>
> 2) [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/): Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.moveItems = function() {
    $(this).children('div:first-of-type').animate(
      500,
      function() {
        $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
      }
    );
  }

  $("#content").moveItems();

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <p>id="container"</p>
  <div id="div-1">
    <p>id="div-1"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-2">
    <p>id="div-2"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-3">
    <p>id="div-3"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-4">
    <p>id="div-4"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `flexbox`, then that's what you want to achieve would be pretty simple thanks to `order` property:

```css
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#div-1 {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>id="container"</p>
  <div id="div-1">
    <p>id="div-1"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-2">
    <p>id="div-2"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-3">
    <p>id="div-3"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div-4">
    <p>id="div-4"</p>
    <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Improvising on the solution by @sujeith (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51811892/2024411) I have created the function such that you can go around rotating all the items from top being pushed to the end of the list.

```
function moveDiv() {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        allChildDivs = document.querySelector("#content").children;
    fragment.appendChild(allChildDivs[0]);
    document.querySelector("#content").appendChild(fragment);
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/nitinsuri/pen/djrpyo

Answer (score 0):

From the suggested answers I used this css:

```
#content {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

#div-1 {
 order: 1;
}
```

and js:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
allChildDivs = document.querySelector("#content").children;
fragment.appendChild(allChildDivs[0]);
document.querySelector("#content").appendChild(fragment);
```

Thank to everyone